# Script In Formula Text Search Result

Tags: javascript, search, hyperlink, formula, netsuite

I have a search result column where I'm using the record ID to pass parameters as a link to a non-netsuite external site I own that is designed for a specific non-NetSuite task.

The link is working great and the formula looks something like this:

```
'<a href="http://www.somesite.com/example_tool.php?internalID='||{internalid}||'&key=some:key:forVerification" target=\"_blank\">Use Tool</a>'
```

However, I'd like to add some script to it by using onClick, and each time I've tried this either I get back invalid expression or the script seems to get stripped out of the link.

I've added what should just be a simple alert window with the record id as a test like this:

```
'<a href="http://www.somesite.com/example_tool.php?internalID='||{internalid}||'&key=some:key:forVerification" target=\"_blank\" onClick=\"alert('||{internalid}||');\">Use Tool</a>'
```

but using the dev tools to inspect this the search result shows up like this:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/example_tool.php?internalID=123456&key=blah:00:buxqod" target="\&quot;_blank\&quot;" onclick="">Use MT Tool With Tracking</a>
```

I'd like to track something simple like which user clicked the link and what day it was, but I'm starting to think that this might not be possible.

Has anyone ever tried doing something like this before?
Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why are you escaping your double quotes, and only the target and onclick pairs? Get rid of the escape slashes.

Comment: @NathanSutherland you're right about that. Someone else had setup these links, and they were working so I didn't bother changing that part before posting this, but it works both with and without the escape slashes.

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree. I believe the escape slashes are your problem, and your example above would work without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a rudimentary attempt on NetSuite's part to prevent XSS attempts, but if you don't need to support Internet Explorer you can get around it using the template literal syntax.

```
'<a href="http://www.somesite.com/example_tool.php?internalID='||{internalid}||'&key=some:key:forVerification" target=\"_blank\" onClick="alert(`' || {internalid} || '`);">Use Tool</a>'
```

Comment: This worked for the example, now I just need to figure out how I can get it to work for the functional solution. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I still think the escaped double quote is a problem ☺, but I was able to duplicate your issue in preview mode (I think it's a result of NetSuite's whence parameter). Run or Save and Run does not encounter the issue. See screenshots of Search Formula Text fields below and corresponding elements when run.

Lazy Loader

[image]

Result

[image]

Element

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dude that is some really cool stuff!
The actual thing I'm trying to get my link to do is record the user name of the current user and the current date to some field in the record that is being clicked. Do you think you can get it to do that?
The alert worked fine but for some reason, maybe like you said about the whence, the nlapi calls are getting stripped out still.